# Configure timeout based on request_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

I want to have different timeouts for different types of requests, for e.g. for /admin I want to have higher timeout.

How do I configure this in unicorn?

Comment: What is it about the /admin route that requires a higher timeout? As far as I know there's no option to configure per-route or per-controller timeouts directly in Unicorn but you can probably solve the problem with [timeout](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) or [rack-timeout](https://github.com/heroku/rack-timeout)

Comment: The /admin is doing some heavy queries, which take longer. As a result of which timeout gets hit and unicorn kills the worker processes in murder_lazy_workers method.